# Paypal SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole not work for recurring payments

Tags: paypal, recurring

i use Paypal ExpressCheckout method for payments.
I want to allow my users buy without paypal account and using their credit card.
[Its work fine](http://oi61.tinypic.com/23it5zt.jpg) when i use one time payment. 
My payment params (excepts currency, signature, username and password) looks like this:

```
'amt'=> '300.00', 
'paymentAction' => 'Sale',
'desc' => 'some desc',
'qty' => 1,
'solutionType' => 'Sole',  <--this option allow buy by credit card w/o pp account
'landingPage' => 'Billing',
```

But when i want to set up recurring payment, [its not working anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHvW6.png). 
My recurring payment params:

```
'amt' => '300.00',
'l_billingType0' => 'RecurringPayments',
'l_billingAgreementDescription0' => 'Some desc',
'solutionType'  => 'Sole',
'landingPage'   => 'Billing',
```

Paypal force user to create pp account in this case :(
PayPal Account Optional it turned to ON in my pp account ofc.

Any idea what wrong i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Pay with Credit or debit card " option is only applicable for the one time payments not for the recurring payments via the API calls .

The only possibility where you see the "Pay with credit card" option when you use the PayPal subscription button and you have the ERP( Enhanced recurring Payments) product on your account .

If you are looking to create the recurring profiles on the credit cards then you must have a Pro account  and the recurring payments add on , then you will be using the API calls to create the recurring Payments directly on your website without even redirecting to the PayPal Page .

Depending on your Pro account type , you will be using the following API's :

For PayPal Payments Pro ( Payflow Edition)

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf

For PayPal Payments Pro ( Direct Edition)

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: wow. its work now! still have 2 questions to you :)
1. Is it possible to pass screen this screen http://oi61.tinypic.com/2e0jtax.jpg and send user to screen with credit or debit card form ? 
2. Why it work for sandbox and not for live? i have business US account with enherence recurring payment tools? (so when i try to activate it now - i see the message: Good news! You've already signed up for Enhanced Recurring Payments. You can create your buttons now.)
thx

Comment: No , there is no control over that page . And regarding your live account , have you signed up for that ? You can sign up at below url : https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_product-go&product=premium_services

Comment: this url redirect me to Recurring payments dashboard in my live account.

Comment: Is there any website where I can check the live account integration?

Comment: no :( It local now. I can give you email link from button generation page. will it help? https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=QJWXMB7FGUSZ4

Comment: Yeah I saw that . Did you make sure that you have turn one toggle in your PayPal account ? Go to this url after logging to the PayPal account :https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments . Here you will see an option "PayPal Account Optional" , change it to yes and then save and try again on your website .

Comment: Yes, its true. I rxperemenred with this option yday and forgot to turn it on. Thx you vm!

Comment: If it worked , accept the answer as it can help others going forward :)